# How to get TotalPages from JOB_INFO_1 (GetJob)

Tags: windows, winapi, printing, gdi, printers

I am calling GetJob() to get the document name and the TotalPages. I always get the TotalPages as Zero. I saw MSDN, it is said if Page Delimiting information is missing, this value will be zero.
Is there a way that I can get the TotalPages or PagesPrinted from GetJob(with any extra settings)

Thanks
Santhi

Comment: Can you share the code that is not working pls

Comment: I am getting the jobID from StartDoc, BOOL result = OpenPrinter(pDCInfo->PrinterName, &hPrinter, NULL);
    if (result)
    {
     DWORD dwCNeeded = 0;

     BOOL bStatus = GetJob(hPrinter, pJobID, 2, 0, 0, &dwCNeeded);
     if (!bStatus && GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
     {
      pJobBuf = new BYTE[dwCNeeded];
     }
  
     bStatus = GetJob(hPrinter, pJobID, 2, pJobBuf, dwCNeeded, &dwCNeeded); 
     if (bStatus)
     {
      pJobData = (PJOB_INFO_2)pJobBuf;
      driveData.FileSize = pJobData->PagesPrinted;
     }
    }

Comment: all other values I am getting from the struct except TotalPages & PrintedPages. I used JOB_INFO_1 & JOB_INFO_2 both

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code in there. It does not belong in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working, I was hooking the StartDoc and getting the JobID & try to call GetJob. At this time the number of pages were zero. I tried hooking the EndJob & call the GetJob just before ending, I got the right number for TotalPages & PagesPrinted. 
Hope this information helps, if any of you see the same problem.